# strange g++ error with simple code about lvalue and assignment

Tags: c++

When I want to compile this code, I have this error :

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:6:24: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
abc = abc + abc + abc = abc +2;
                      ^
```

test.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int abc = 5;
    abc = abc + abc + abc = abc +2;
    std::cout << "abc = " << abc << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It's a strange compiler behavior cuz for me this code is compilable.

Comment: *for me this code is compilable*  If the code were compilable, you woudn't be getting a compiler error.  What are you leaving out of your question?

Comment: What do you expect `abc = abc + abc + abc = abc +2;` to do? It will help us explain where you went wrong.

Comment: What you have is like saying 5+5+5 = 5 + 2. That would be a bit odd, don't you think?

Comment: Please don't spam tags. This has nothing to do with gcc, g++ and c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can see the operator precedence https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

The statement

```
abc = abc + abc + abc = abc +2;
```

is equivalent to

```
abc + abc + abc = abc +2;
abc = abc + abc + abc;
```

The first line

```
abc + abc + abc = abc +2;
```

is not valid because the expression

```
abc + abc + abc
```

is an rvalue. You can't assign a value to it.

Comment: thank you Thomas :) 

I think that this code should do this in a perfect world : "abc = (abc + abc + (abc = abc +2));"

your response is good of course ^^

Comment: You'll have to split that up a bit more. I think you're wanting `abc = abc +2;` and on the next line `abc = abc + abc+ abc;`. Don't fear breaking an expression down into multiple steps. Usually it makes the debugging easier (you can snoop in and see the outcomes of the stages more easily) and the extra spacing and steps likely won't mean a thing to the compiler.  Write the simplest, easiest to read code you possibly can.

Comment: Thanks :) I want only to test my own compiler and compare it with gcc/g++